# How to subtract two columns of Longvarchar in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have `TABLE1` with columns `COL1`,`COL2` defined as `LongVarChar` in Oracle.

Every time user loads a record to TABLE1, COL1 will have the old value and COL2 will have the old value + new value. i.e.

For ex:

```
COL1            COL2
                Bat
Bat             Bat Ball
Bat Ball        Bat Ball Wicket
Bat Ball Wicket Bat Ball Wicket Stump
```

To get the only new value, i am planning to delete contents of COL2 from COL1 contents..I think this is a pretty bad idea..

I tried the usual "-" operator and it says `"Expected Numeric but received CLOB"`

But does any one any better idea or how to accomplish this?

Thanks so much

Comment: `LongVarChar` is not a data type in Oracle.  Do you mean `CLOB`?  Or `LONG`?  Or `VARCHAR2`?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean Varchar2, and (as in your example), each old value is separated by an additional space, then something like this should work:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col2, NVL(LENGTH(col1)+2,0)) "New Value" FROM TABLE1
```

eg:

```
select substr('Bat', nvl(length(null)+2,0)) from dual;
```

results in 'Bat'

```
select substr('Bat Ball', nvl(length('Bat')+2,0)) from dual;
```

results in 'Ball'

---

But if you're actually talking about a `CLOB` datatype, then substitute:

```
dbms_lob.substr( colX, 4000, 1)
```

instead of colX (where X is 1 or 2)

[This will give you the first 4000 bytes of the CLOB - in order to get more, you'd have to use PL/SQL]

Comment: Excellent Gerrat..It solved the problem in 2 min..Thanks for your time